# InvalidUseOfMatchersException with mockito using matchers

Tags: java, mockito, matcher

I am working with mockito and I am getting the next issue:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (an instance of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException and exception with message a string containing "")
     but: an instance of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException <org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.rccl.middleware.kidsclub.engine.services.KidServiceTest.saveKid_kidExist_throwException(KidServiceTest.java:97)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

This is my test code:

```
    @Mock
    private KidRepository kidRepository;

    @Mock
    private RoomService roomService;

    @Test
    public void saveKid_kidExist_throwException() {
        given(kidRepository.existsById(anyString())).willReturn(true);
        given(roomService.existShipRoomDefault()).willReturn(true);

        expectedException.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        expectedException.expectMessage(startsWith("Kid already registered"));
        KidDTO kidDTO = MockDTO.buildKidDTO();

        service.saveKid(kidDTO);

        then(kidRepository).should().existsById(anyString());
    }
```

This is the code of the saveKid method which is sending exceptions basically:

```
       if (!validateShipRoomExist()) {
            log.warn("::: The ShipRoom document doesn't exist.");
            throw new RoomNotFoundException(NO_ROOMS_IN_DATABASE);
        }

        if (validateKidAlreadyRegistered(kidDTO.getId())) {
            log.warn("::: Trying to persist a Kid already persisted with ID [{}]", kidDTO.getId());
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Kid already registered with ID [%s]", kidDTO.getId()));
        }
```

And these are the methods called:

```
        private boolean validateShipRoomExist() {
            return roomService.existShipRoomDefault();
        }

        public boolean validateKidAlreadyRegistered(@NotNull String kidId) {
            return kidRepository.existsById(kidId);
        }
```

The next is my code in the roomService:

```
public boolean existShipRoomDefault() {
        return roomRepository.existsById(DEFAULT_AGGREGATOR_ID);
 }
```

The problem is in this method which has the problem, even though I am using a string anyString() in this test. I don't understand what is happening in this case. an interesting think is that in debug mode the test doesn't fails if I have a breakpoint.

Comment: ok, I supossed the same, but I ned to evaluate the error message, is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: the kidto is  an  new object created with info in the MockDTO class, it is what you mean?

Comment: Err, what type is `expectedException`. And what is `then(kidRepository).should().existsById(anyString());` supposed to do?

Comment: @GhostCat: I suppose its [`ExpectedException`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) and the line is supposed to be a verify on the `existsById` method. But its unreachable due to how the exception handling works.

Answer (score 0):

`BDDMockito.startsWith` is a Matcher method, which you used on `expectedException.expectMessage` which is unrelated to mocking.

If you want to evaluate the message of the exception you should compare it to the complete message.

An adjusted test could look like this:

```
@Test
public void saveKid_kidExist_throwException() {

    // ...

    KidDTO kidDto = new KidDTO();
    kidDto.setId("1");

    expectedException.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    expectedException.expectMessage("Kid already registered with ID [1]");
    service.saveKid(kidDto);
}
```

Since I don't know what the MockDTO class is doing and I assume its easy to create an instance of `KidDTO` on your own, I just do that in the example above.

An alternative would be - in case `kidDTO` is a mock - to define:

```
BDDMockito.given(kidDto.getId()).willReturn("1");
```